# SQL Server query results in error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'"

Tags: t-sql

I am writing a SQL query but keep getting syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'

What could be causing this issue? I have tried looking for all the obvious things but I am not picking up on it and I looked at previous posts too, see query below:

```
(/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT ALLGENEDX.[id]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Chr]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Start]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[End]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[ref]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[alt]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Func#refGene]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Gene#refGene]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Otherinfo]
      ,CASE WHEN OTHERINFO = 'HOM' THEN CASE WHEN PARENT_OTHERINFO = 'HET' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE WHEN PARENT_OTHERINFO <> 'HOM' AND PARENT_AMMOUNT > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END AS 'PARENT_INFO'
      ,CASE WHEN OTHERINFO = 'HOM' THEN CASE WHEN SIBLING_OTHERINFO = 'HET' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE WHEN SIBLING_OTHERINFO <> 'HOM' AND (SIBLING_AMMOUNT = 1 OR SIBLING_AMMOUNT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END END AS 'SIBLING_INFO' 
      FROM [Exome Data].[dbo].[ALLGENEDX],
(SELECT [ID],
[Chr],
[Start],
[end],
[REF], 
[ALT],
[Func#refGene],
[GENE#REFGENE],
[OTHERINFO] AS PARENT_OTHERINFO, 
COUNT (ID) OVER (PARTITION BY 
[Chr],
[Start],
[End],
[REF], 
[ALT],
[Func#refGene],
[GENE#REFGENE],
[OTHERINFO]) AS PARENT_AMMOUNT 
FROM [Exome Data].DBO.ALLGENEDX 
WHERE ID IN ('1646304GD', '1646307GD'))AS PARENT, 
(SELECT [id],
[Chr],
[Start],
[end],
[REF], 
[ALT],
[Func#refGene],
[GENE#REFGENE],
[OTHERINFO] AS SIBLING_OTHERINFO, 
COUNT (ID) OVER (PARTITION BY
[Chr],
[Start],
[end],
[REF], 
[ALT],
[Func#refGene],
[GENE#REFGENE],
[OTHERINFO]) AS SIBLING_AMMOUNT 
FROM [Exome Data].DBO.ALLGENEDX 
WHERE ID IN ('1646310GD', '1646314GD', '1646317GD', '1646320GD', '1646325GD'))AS SIBLING
   WHERE SIBLING.[CHR]=ALLGENEDX.Chr
  AND SIBLING.[START]=ALLGENEDX.[START]
  AND SIBLING.[END]=ALLGENEDX.[END]
  AND SIBLING.[REF]=ALLGENEDX.[REF]
  AND SIBLING.[ALT]= ALLGENEDX.[ALT] 
  AND SIBLING.[GENE#REFGENE]=ALLGENEDX.[GENE#REFGENE]
  AND PARENT.[CHR]=ALLGENEDX.[Chr]
  AND PARENT.[START]=ALLGENEDX.[START]
  AND PARENT.[END]=ALLGENEDX.[END]
  AND PARENT.[REF]=ALLGENEDX.[REF]
  AND PARENT.[ALT]= ALLGENEDX.[ALT] 
  AND PARENT.[GENE#REFGENE]=ALLGENEDX.[GENE#REFGENE]
  AND  ALLGENEDX.ID= '1646299GD' AND ALLGENEDX.Func#refGene = 'exonic' 
  AND (EXAC_FREQ<'0.005' OR EXAC_FREQ IS NULL)
  AND ([1000G_ALL]<'0.005' OR [1000G_ALL] IS NULL)
  AND (GNOMAD_EXOME_ALL<'0.005' OR GNOMAD_EXOME_ALL IS NULL)
  HAVING CASE WHEN OTHERINFO = 'HOM' THEN CASE WHEN PARENT_OTHERINFO = 'HET' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE WHEN PARENT_OTHERINFO <> 'HOM' AND PARENT_AMMOUNT > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END > 0
  OR CASE WHEN OTHERINFO = 'HOM' THEN CASE WHEN SIBLING_OTHERINFO = 'HET' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE WHEN SIBLING_OTHERINFO <> 'HOM' AND (SIBLING_AMMOUNT = 1 OR SIBLING_AMMOUNT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END END > 0
  GROUP BY ALLGENEDX.[id]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Chr]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Start]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[End]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[ref]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[alt]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Func#refGene]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Gene#refGene]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Otherinfo]
      ,[PARENT_OTHERINFO]
      ,[SIBLING_OTHERINFO]
     ORDER BY len ALLGENEDX.[Chr], Chr, start;/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT ALLGENEDX.[id]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Chr]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Start]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[End]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[ref]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[alt]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Func#refGene]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Gene#refGene]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Otherinfo]
      ,CASE WHEN OTHERINFO = 'HOM' THEN CASE WHEN PARENT_OTHERINFO = 'HET' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE WHEN PARENT_OTHERINFO <> 'HOM' AND PARENT_AMMOUNT > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END AS 'PARENT_INFO'
      ,CASE WHEN OTHERINFO = 'HOM' THEN CASE WHEN SIBLING_OTHERINFO = 'HET' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE WHEN SIBLING_OTHERINFO <> 'HOM' AND (SIBLING_AMMOUNT = 1 OR SIBLING_AMMOUNT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END END AS 'SIBLING_INFO' 
      FROM [Exome Data].[dbo].[ALLGENEDX],
(SELECT [ID],
[Chr],
[Start],
[end],
[REF], 
[ALT],
[Func#refGene],
[GENE#REFGENE],
[OTHERINFO] AS PARENT_OTHERINFO, 
COUNT (ID) OVER (PARTITION BY 
[Chr],
[Start],
[End],
[REF], 
[ALT],
[Func#refGene],
[GENE#REFGENE],
[OTHERINFO]) AS PARENT_AMMOUNT 
FROM [Exome Data].DBO.ALLGENEDX 
WHERE ID IN ('1646304GD', '1646307GD'))AS PARENT, 
(SELECT [id],
[Chr],
[Start],
[end],
[REF], 
[ALT],
[Func#refGene],
[GENE#REFGENE],
[OTHERINFO] AS SIBLING_OTHERINFO, 
COUNT (ID) OVER (PARTITION BY
[Chr],
[Start],
[end],
[REF], 
[ALT],
[Func#refGene],
[GENE#REFGENE],
[OTHERINFO]) AS SIBLING_AMMOUNT 
FROM [Exome Data].DBO.ALLGENEDX 
WHERE ID IN ('1646310GD', '1646314GD', '1646317GD', '1646320GD', '1646325GD'))AS SIBLING
   WHERE SIBLING.[CHR]=ALLGENEDX.Chr
  AND SIBLING.[START]=ALLGENEDX.[START]
  AND SIBLING.[END]=ALLGENEDX.[END]
  AND SIBLING.[REF]=ALLGENEDX.[REF]
  AND SIBLING.[ALT]= ALLGENEDX.[ALT] 
  AND SIBLING.[GENE#REFGENE]=ALLGENEDX.[GENE#REFGENE]
  AND PARENT.[CHR]=ALLGENEDX.[Chr]
  AND PARENT.[START]=ALLGENEDX.[START]
  AND PARENT.[END]=ALLGENEDX.[END]
  AND PARENT.[REF]=ALLGENEDX.[REF]
  AND PARENT.[ALT]= ALLGENEDX.[ALT] 
  AND PARENT.[GENE#REFGENE]=ALLGENEDX.[GENE#REFGENE]
  AND  ALLGENEDX.ID= '1646299GD' AND ALLGENEDX.Func#refGene = 'exonic' 
  AND (EXAC_FREQ<'0.005' OR EXAC_FREQ IS NULL)
  AND ([1000G_ALL]<'0.005' OR [1000G_ALL] IS NULL)
  AND (GNOMAD_EXOME_ALL<'0.005' OR GNOMAD_EXOME_ALL IS NULL)
  HAVING CASE WHEN OTHERINFO = 'HOM' THEN CASE WHEN PARENT_OTHERINFO = 'HET' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE WHEN PARENT_OTHERINFO <> 'HOM' AND PARENT_AMMOUNT > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END > 0
  OR CASE WHEN OTHERINFO = 'HOM' THEN CASE WHEN SIBLING_OTHERINFO = 'HET' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE WHEN SIBLING_OTHERINFO <> 'HOM' AND (SIBLING_AMMOUNT = 1 OR SIBLING_AMMOUNT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END END > 0
  GROUP BY ALLGENEDX.[id]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Chr]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Start]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[End]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[ref]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[alt]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Func#refGene]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Gene#refGene]
      ,ALLGENEDX.[Otherinfo]
      ,[PARENT_OTHERINFO]
      ,[SIBLING_OTHERINFO]
     ORDER BY len ALLGENEDX.[Chr], Chr, start;
```

Comment: Could you share your script please?

Comment: What query? What database?

Comment: for some reason its not allowing me to post the script its saying its too long. How can I add it?

Comment: Click the code button in the editor and paste the code inside there. Else just link to paste bin.

Comment: Why do they force you to lengthen your question? I couldnt get the query to post because they wanted me to have more text in my question I hope asking the question twice makes them happy :)

Comment: That's two queries, which one fails?

Comment: The error is on line 72  on group from group by

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have HAVING before GROUP BY, it needs to be in the opposite order.

There is also an extra left parenthesis on the first row for some reason.

```
 GROUP BY ALLGENEDX.[id]
  ,ALLGENEDX.[Chr]
  ...
  ,[SIBLING_OTHERINFO]
 HAVING CASE 
     WHEN OTHERINFO = 'HOM' THEN ...
```

The ORDER BY contains the word "len", which seems wrong, I removed it but you might want to double check that.

```
 ORDER BY ALLGENEDX.[Chr], Chr, start;
```

Below is the complete where/group/having/order for the second query

```
WHERE SIBLING.[CHR]=ALLGENEDX.Chr AND SIBLING.[START]=ALLGENEDX.[START] AND SIBLING.[END]=ALLGENEDX.[END] AND SIBLING.[REF]=ALLGENEDX.[REF] AND SIBLING.[ALT]= ALLGENEDX.[ALT] AND SIBLING.[GENE#REFGENE]=ALLGENEDX.[GENE#REFGENE] AND PARENT.[CHR]=ALLGENEDX.[Chr] AND PARENT.[START]=ALLGENEDX.[START] AND PARENT.[END]=ALLGENEDX.[END] AND PARENT.[REF]=ALLGENEDX.[REF] AND PARENT.[ALT]= ALLGENEDX.[ALT] AND PARENT.[GENE#REFGENE]=ALLGENEDX.[GENE#REFGENE] AND ALLGENEDX.ID= '1646299GD' AND ALLGENEDX.Func#refGene = 'exonic' AND (EXAC_FREQ<'0.005' OR EXAC_FREQ IS NULL) AND ([1000G_ALL]<'0.005' OR [1000G_ALL] IS NULL) AND (GNOMAD_EXOME_ALL<'0.005' OR GNOMAD_EXOME_ALL IS NULL)
GROUP BY ALLGENEDX.[id],ALLGENEDX.[Chr],ALLGENEDX.[Start],ALLGENEDX.[End],ALLGENEDX.[ref],ALLGENEDX.[alt],ALLGENEDX.[Func#refGene],ALLGENEDX.[Gene#refGene],ALLGENEDX.[Otherinfo],[PARENT_OTHERINFO],[SIBLING_OTHERINFO]
HAVING CASE WHEN OTHERINFO = 'HOM' THEN CASE WHEN PARENT_OTHERINFO = 'HET' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE WHEN PARENT_OTHERINFO <> 'HOM' AND PARENT_AMMOUNT > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END > 0 OR CASE WHEN OTHERINFO = 'HOM' THEN CASE WHEN SIBLING_OTHERINFO = 'HET' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE WHEN SIBLING_OTHERINFO <> 'HOM' AND (SIBLING_AMMOUNT = 1 OR SIBLING_AMMOUNT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END END > 0
ORDER BY ALLGENEDX.[Chr], Chr, start;
```

Comment: When I did that this error messages popped up: 
Column 'PARENT.PARENT_AMMOUNT' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 82
Column 'SIBLING.SIBLING_AMMOUNT' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 82
Column 'SIBLING.SIBLING_AMMOUNT' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user9807160 I did not see any error in my editor, are you sure you got all lines when switching order for having and group by? There is also a problem with ORDER BY that I forgot to include.

Comment: I think I did. But to be clear which group by are you telling me to switch? I switched the last group by to be above having case when that is 2 lines above it. And yes the order by did not work. What is the issue with that? It has worked on other queries?

Comment: @user9807160, both queries has the same issue so both needs to be fixed in the same way. Are you sure order by has worked earlier? what is `len` then?

Comment: @user9807160, I included a condensed version of the end of the 2nd query in my answer.

Comment: No, its still not working. Here are the error messages:

Comment: Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 81
Column 'PARENT.PARENT_AMMOUNT' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 82
Column 'SIBLING.SIBLING_AMMOUNT' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 82
Column 'SIBLING.SIBLING_AMMOUNT' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Msg 169, Level 15, State 1, Line 84
A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.

Comment: The reason I had 'len' in there was because it did not return the chromosomes in number order but rather 1 and then 10 and 2 then 20 etc... And by adding len it allowed me to get them back in numerical order by going with the length of the string

Comment: the data in that column is chr1,chr2...chr10...chr20 so the string length gave me the ability to control the numbers and  chars

Comment: @user9807160 Well I have helped you with the group by/having bug in your code which this question was about, you need to take it from here since you are the one with access to the database.